# How do I access items in the StackExchange inbox

Tags: support, global-inbox

I asked a question and I can see a reply in my inbox. If I click on the message it takes me to a reply on the the question I asked, but it doesn't appear to be the same answer as the precis I can see of the inbox message doesn't match the answer on the question page.

Comment: Can you add screenshots to make it clear?

Comment: It might be that the answer has since been deleted for whatever reason, so you won't be able to see it, you'll just get taken to the main question page instead. Or the answer has been edited since the inbox notification. Has the answer got an 'edited' timestamp on it?

Comment: I can't post images as I don't have enough of a reputation, only having joined yesterday to ask a PayPal question. Also, I can't see an edited flag on the answer. The question and answer is on this page http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16944967/paypal-expresscheckout-limit-ship-to-country

Answer (score 1):

The only way such thing can happen as far as I can tell is the answer was edited *during its grace period*. There is 5 minutes grace period after each edit (or after initial time of posting) during which any further edit is not recorded as a revision but merged into the original revision.

The only way to confirm this is by asking the answer author in a comment, something like "Did you edit your answer shortly after posting it?".

Comment: I shall ask the answer author, thanks for the suggestion.